# Composer does not recognize Class "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: "Class" Not Found"

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I am trying to use this wrapper:

https://github.com/larislackers/php-binance

Already installed it, but for some reason the class `BinanceApiContainer` is not getting found.

**My code**

```
<?php
  require 'C:\Users\Francisco\vendor\autoload.php';
  $bac = new BinanceApiContainer('<your_key>', '<your_secret>');
?>
```

Does anyone knows about this? Thank you.

**Error encountered**

> "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'BinanceApiContainer' not found in
>   C:\php\servidor\htdocs\binance_proj\binance.php:11 Stack trace: #0
>   {main} thrown in C:\php\servidor\htdocs\binance_proj\binance.php on
>   line 11"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a `BinanceApiContainer` class in the global namespace.

```
use Larislackers\BinanceApi\BinanceApiContainer;

// ...

$bac = new BinanceApiContainer('<your_key>', '<your_secret>');
```

Comment: Thanks Federkun. I can spot the error now, would be the same if I have originally written: $bac = new Larislackers\BinanceApi\BinanceApiContainer('<your_key>', '<your_secret>');

Comment: That's equivalent, yeah.